Can sequence of random variables with mean $0$ and bounded variance diverge to $\pm \infty$?
Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables (not necessarily independent nor identically distributed, just think of general sequence of r.v's) with mean $0$ and bounded variance, i.e. there exists $0<C<\infty$ such that $Var(X_n)\leq C\,\,\forall n$. Can we say that the sequence cannot diverge to $\pm \infty$ almost surely, i.e. $$\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to \infty} X_n = \pm \infty) = 0\,,$$ or is there a counterexample to this?

$P(|X_n|\to \infty)=0$. Prove this using  $P(|X_n|>M) \le \frac C {M^{2}}$.

Suppose $P(\liminf_n|X_n|=\infty)>0$. Then $\infty =E[\liminf_n|X_n|^2]\leq \liminf_nE[|X_n|^2]\leq C$ by Fatou, a contradiction. Therefore $P(\lim_n|X_n|=\infty)\leq P(\liminf_n|X_n|=\infty)=0$.

Thanks so much @Snoop !

We can certainly have a distribution with bounded mean and variance yet the distribution itself is unbounded. Thus a sequence drawn from this distribution would also be unbounded. Most likely it would oscillate at some points and have no limit at all.
The normal distribution is one such example, but an even more intuitive example involes the "Tower of Hanoi sequence" (I name it for the sequence of moves required to solve this ancient puzzle):
$1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,...,$
$\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge1}: a_{2n-1}=1,a_{2n}=1+a_n$
This is essentially an exponential distribution with both mean and variance equal to $2$, but it is unbounded as surely as the Tower of Hanoi can be solved with an arbitrarily large number of stories.

For the sequence of iid normal, I don't think there exists a limit (even to $\pm \infty$) at all from Kolmogorov 0-1 law. As for the Tower of Hanoi sequence, it oscillates between $1$ and arbitrarily large numbers, not diverging to $\infty$ in itself.

Then quite plausibly the outcome with probability $1-\epsilon$ is, indeed, no limit at all.

Yeah, but that leaves $\epsilon$ probability where the limit may (or may not) exist. I cannot use the Kolmogorov 0-1 law as I throw out the independence assumption.
